# How would you make a navigation bar for mobile

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to make this navigation bar usable for mobile devices, I have tried multiple method by watching youtube using @media or hamburger method, but none of them seem to work for this, Unless I rewrite the html to match how they use it.

This is my original code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Waverly Farm: Home</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class = "header">
            <div class = "logo">Waverely Farm</div>
            <nav class = "navbar">
                <a href ="index.html">Home</a>
                <a href ="about_us.html">About Us</a>
                <a href ="services.html">Services</a>
                <a href ="shop.html">Shop</a>
                <a href ="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried adding @media but I am not sure how to use it for this type of navigation bar

````
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 100px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 100;
}
.logo{
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.navbar a{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.navbar a::before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    transition: .3s;
}

.navbar a:hover::before{
    width: 100%;
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector(".mobile-menu-icon").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
    var header = document.querySelector(".header");

    if (navbar.style.display === "flex") {
        navbar.style.display = "none";
        header.classList.remove("mobile-menu-open");
    } else {
        navbar.style.display = "flex";
        header.classList.add("mobile-menu-open");
    }
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 100px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 100;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
}

.navbar a {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.mobile-menu-icon {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 4px 0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar {
        display: none;
        flex-direction: column;
        position: absolute;
        top: 60px;
        left: 0;
        background: aquamarine;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .navbar a {
        margin: 10px 0;
    }

    .mobile-menu-icon {
        display: flex;
    }
}

.header.mobile-menu-open .navbar {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Waverly Farm: Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="logo">Waverely Farm</div>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="about_us.html">About Us</a>
            <a href="services.html">Services</a>
            <a href="shop.html">Shop</a>
            <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="mobile-menu-icon">
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need JavaScript if you want to create an accessible mobile menu including a toggle button. It's actually quiet simple to do that, here's a approach I like to use:

#### HTML

First you'll need to add a button element for toggling the menu within the `<nav>` element. It's also a good idea to wrap the menu links in a list element to group them semantically.

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="logo">Waverely Farm</div>
  <nav class="navbar" aria-label="main">
    <button
      class="menu-toggle"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-controls="menu"
    >Menu</button>

    <ul id="menu" class="menu" role="list">
      <li>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="about_us.html">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="services.html">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="shop.html">Shop</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The ARIA attributes (starting with `aria-`) of the button element help screen reader users to better understand and use the menu. In this case, `aria-expanded` indicates the state of the menu (open/closed).

#### CSS

We can now use the `aria-expanded` state to conditionally add styles in CSS.

```css
:where(ul, ol)[role="list"] {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .menu-toggle {
    display: initial;
  }
  button[aria-expanded="false"] + ul {
  display: none;
  }
  .menu {
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    inset: 130px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .menu a {
    color: inherit;
  }
}
```

The styles in `.menu` are just an example, customize them to make it look the way you want.

#### JavaScript

And finally add an `EventListener` for the menu button to toggle the state of `aria-expanded` to `true` or `false`:

```js
const menuButton = document.querySelector(".menu-toggle");

menuButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const state = menuButton.getAttribute("aria-expanded") === "false";
  menuButton.setAttribute("aria-expanded", state);
});
```

---

I hope this helps. If anything is not clear, feel free to ask.

Comment: There actually is a no-JS way to do this; search for "checkbox hack menu". However the trick has its limitations and yes using Javascript is strongly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a CSS framework like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/):

Add this to your page head

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

then do something like this:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you're going to make a suggestion, also add some explanation. Why is Bootstrap a consideration?